# Pandas/Python: 2D histogram fails with value error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, histogram2d

I am trying to create a 2D histrogram from a Pandas data frame "rates"
The X and Y axis are supposed to be transforms from the dataframe, i.e., the X and Y axis are 'scaled' from the original frame columns and the bin heigths are according to the number of hits in each x/y bin.

```
import numpy, pylab, pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list(rates.columns.values)
['sizes', 'transfers', 'positioning']

x=(rates["sizes"]/1024./1024.)
y=((rates["sizes"]/rates["transfers"])/1024.)+rates["positioning]
```

so, I try to feed them into a numpy 2D histogram with

```
histo, xedges, yedges = numpy.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(100,100))
```

However, this fails with

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 650, in histogram2d
 hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py" line 363, in histogramdd
 decimal = int(-log10(mindiff)) + 6
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I have already dropped all NaN in my rame 'rates.dropna()' - but actually from the error I guess, that it is not due to NaNs in my frame.

Maybe somebody has an idea, what goes wrong here?

Comment: This might be difficult to answer if we don't know what data you're using as input. Could you find the smallest possible arrays that give the error, along with the version of numpy that you're using?

Comment: Hi, probably I have to ask a stupid question first how to get a subset plottet:
I tried to plot a slice, e.g.,

     H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x[1:1000], y[1:1000], bins=(10,10))

but got an attribute error

    AttributeError: The dimension of bins must be equal to the dimension of the sample x.

I would have assumed, that the dimensions should be equal, or??
My versions are numpy:1.8.2 and pandas:0.15.2,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with help from @jme I got on the right track

I had not checked for a problematic value pair 
x:y = 0.0:inf
can obviously not be a good 2D histogram vector, i.e., when transforming the original values I have to catch such cases.

another thing: numpy histogram had some issues for me with DataFrame series, so I had to get a proper numpy.arrary from the series to plot them properly, e.g.,

```
histo, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(np.array(x[1:MAX]),np.array(y[1:MAX]), bins=(100,100))
```

for slicing the series up to some variable MAX