# Histogram2D in python fails with ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, histogram2d

Possibly a duplicate of [Pandas/Python: 2D histogram fails with value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008432/pandas-python-2d-histogram-fails-with-value-error#). But the solution proposed there is not working for me.

I am trying to use numpy histogram2d on 2 arrays each of size 55812. When I run the command `np.histogram2d(x,y)`, I get the following error:

```
np.histogram2d(np.array(nlx_angle[50000:55000]),np.array(nlx_speed[50000:55000]), bins=(100,100))
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\twodim_base.py", line 714, in histogram2d
hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 802, in histogramdd 
decimal = int(-log10(mindiff)) + 6

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I have already removed all the NaN from the data. Also, the answer to the question (link above) suggested using a subset of data, but for my application, I need to use the entire data. I am using numpy version 1.11.0

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT 1**

I used np.where`(nlx_angle==np.nan)` and `np.where(nlx_speed==np.nan)` to check for NaN and all it returned is `(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))`

Comment: What are the min and max of `nlx_angle[50000:55000]` and `nlx_speed[50000:55000]`?  Check with `print(np.min(nlx_angle[50000:55000]))`, etc.

Comment: Pretty hard to debug data we don't have. But are you absolutely certain you filtered out the `NaN`s properly? Can we see how you filtered them out? Seems like the error is pretty clear: it can't convert the float `NaN` to an integer.

Comment: Your issue isn't NaNs in your input, the issue is negative numbers in your input.  Somewhere in there you're running through `log10`, which produces a NaN if you give it a negative number.